# User defined function in Chapel has odd behavior .type vs .eltType

Tags: chapel

I wanted to write a concatenation function, so I came up with

```
proc concat(x:[], y:[]) {
  const d:int = x.size + y.size;
  var v:[1..d] x.type;

  writeln("\n d: ", d);
  writeln("\n x.domain: ", x.domain);
  writeln("\n y.domain: ", y.domain);
  var k = 1;
  for i in x.domain {
    v[k] = x[i];
    writeln("i: ", i, " k: ", k,  " x[i]: ", x[i], " v[k]: ", v[k]);
    k += 1;
  }
  for i in y.domain {
    v[k] = y[i];
    writeln("i: ", i, " k: ", k, " y[i]: ", y[i], " v[k]: ", v[k]);
    k += 1;
  }
  writeln("\n v: ", v);

  return v;
}
```

But it has a very odd output

```
var x: [1..3] real = [1.1, 2.2, 3.3],
    y: [9..11] real = [9.9, 10.10, 11.11];

var z = concat(x,y);
writeln(z);
```

Produces

```
 d: 6

 x.domain: {1..3}

 y.domain: {9..11}
i: 1 k: 1 x[i]: 1.1 v[k]: 1.1 1.1 1.1
i: 2 k: 2 x[i]: 2.2 v[k]: 2.2 2.2 2.2
i: 3 k: 3 x[i]: 3.3 v[k]: 3.3 3.3 3.3
i: 9 k: 4 y[i]: 9.9 v[k]: 9.9 9.9 9.9
i: 10 k: 5 y[i]: 10.1 v[k]: 10.1 10.1 10.1
i: 11 k: 6 y[i]: 11.11 v[k]: 11.11 11.11 11.11

 v: 1.1 1.1 1.1 2.2 2.2 2.2 3.3 3.3 3.3 9.9 9.9 9.9 10.1 10.1 10.1 11.11 11.11 11.11
1.1 1.1 1.1 2.2 2.2 2.2 3.3 3.3 3.3 9.9 9.9 9.9 10.1 10.1 10.1 11.11 11.11 11.11
```

This is kind of mystifying.

Comment: As a suggestion: If the title for this issue were changed to something like "`.type` vs. `.eltType`" or "`.type` on arrays", it'd be more likely to help other SO readers who didn't happen to write this specific concat() routine down the road... :)

Comment: Hmm, I didn't know that was the problem at the outset but I see your point.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not faulting your choice of original title, just trying to make the result more useful to future readers...  Thanks for the update.

Comment: Using your suggestion, I implemented a `concat` function for Chapel [here](https://deep6ai.github.io/numsuch/modules/src/MatrixOps.html#MatrixOps.concat)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks as though your code has confused `.type` and `.eltType`.  Given an array variable like `var A: [1..3] real;`, `A.type` is effectively `[1..3] real` while `A.eltType` is simply `real`.  So when you declarde:

```
var v:[1..d] x.type;
```

rather than getting the array of `real` values that you intended, you're actually declaring an array whose elements are themselves arrays of `real` values.

Then, since Chapel supports promoted assignment from a scalar to an array (e.g., `A = 0.0` would be an easy way to zero out my `A` array above), when you're copying elements from your original arrays to `v`, each array element of `v` is storing the value in each of its positions, resulting in the triplication of the values.

Changing the declaration of `v` to:

```
var v:[1..d] x.eltType;
```

should give you what you want.  [Here's the corrected version **online**](https://tio.run/##jVFBboMwELz7FStOQbGsODmB1V/0Rn1A4KoWFJDjUkyVt9Nd0ySo7SFcPDszmlmb6q0cTLssY@lgyqGQQpw0OFO28EST5HAURw4npDkD/AK6MiGkvNsykXGQByEPeEiSFGOUOKNa9V1V@t3EQ6rYp7PetN1uRswG11c3OS80x@xCp/CFPUifPdS57TxmTOJsZwN7CBEoNFD8mNO@tUbdtP45DKigdC1JXjpMgIRDnapf/CTq/r20XZSvwx9X2LrC1kX1DW4maXjtHViw99R4BTQVjabtC6tVJG7ZNiZaDgk0ETYcEJNz3QgBiZQQCQLpGtLA/qf3su0O/3aHx7qTaFyv@XD19qXG1ZrGH@CM/3DIKXZZlm8).

```
var x: [1.. 3] real = [1.1, 2.2, 3.3],
    y: [9..11] real = [9.9, 10.10, 11.11];

var z = concat( x, y );
writeln( z );

proc concat( x:[], y:[] ) {
     const d:int = x.size + y.size;
  // var   v:[1..d] x.type;    // ------------------------------------ FAIL
                               /*     d: 6
                               x.domain: {1..3}
                               y.domain: {9..11}

                               i:   1, k:   1, x[i]:    1.10, v[k]: 1.1 1.1 1.1
                               i:   2, k:   2, x[i]:    2.20, v[k]: 2.2 2.2 2.2
                               i:   3, k:   3, x[i]:    3.30, v[k]: 3.3 3.3 3.3
                               i:   9, k:   4, y[i]:    9.90, v[k]: 9.9 9.9 9.9
                               i:  10, k:   5, y[i]:   10.10, v[k]: 10.1 10.1 10.1
                               i:  11, k:   6, y[i]:   11.11, v[k]: 11.11 11.11 11.11

                               v:
                               1.1 1.1 1.1 2.2 2.2 2.2 3.3 3.3 3.3 9.9 9.9 9.9 10.1 10.1 10.1 11.11 11.11 11.11
                               1.1 1.1 1.1 2.2 2.2 2.2 3.3 3.3 3.3 9.9 9.9 9.9 10.1 10.1 10.1 11.11 11.11 11.11
                               */
     var   v:[1..d] x.eltType; // ------------------------------------ PASS
                               /*     d: 6
                               x.domain: {1..3}
                               y.domain: {9..11}

                               i:   1, k:   1, x[i]:    1.10, v[k]: 1.1
                               i:   2, k:   2, x[i]:    2.20, v[k]: 2.2
                               i:   3, k:   3, x[i]:    3.30, v[k]: 3.3
                               i:   9, k:   4, y[i]:    9.90, v[k]: 9.9
                               i:  10, k:   5, y[i]:   10.10, v[k]: 10.1
                               i:  11, k:   6, y[i]:   11.11, v[k]: 11.11

                               v:
                               1.1 2.2 3.3 9.9 10.1 11.11
                               1.1 2.2 3.3 9.9 10.1 11.11
                               */
     writeln( "\n       d: ", d );
     writeln(   "x.domain: ", x.domain );
     writeln(   "y.domain: ", y.domain );
     var k = 1;
     for i in x.domain {
         v[k] = x[i];
      // writeln("i: ", i, " k: ", k,  " x[i]: ", x[i], " v[k]: ", v[k]);
         writef( "i: %{###},", i ); writef( " k: %{###},", k ); writef( " x[i]: %{####.##},", x[i] ); writeln( " v[k]: ", v[k] );
         k += 1;
     }
     for i in y.domain {
         v[k] = y[i];
      // writeln("i: ", i, " k: ", k, " y[i]: ", y[i], " v[k]: ", v[k]);
         writef( "i: %{###},", i ); writef( " k: %{###},", k ); writef( " y[i]: %{####.##},", y[i] ); writeln( " v[k]: ", v[k] );
         k += 1;
     }
     writeln( "\nv:\n", v );

     return v;
}
```

( [and both alternatives, side by side, left for any further experimentations](https://tio.run/##tVRda9swFH22f8XFYdAPT4nirhCbPfRlMNjDoH1L/WBilxpnTnA9z2rIb8/u1YelpO2oGRVIlnTPuZLPPWj1mG2L9eHQZQ30MSw5YxCl0BTZGr7SkocwZ/MQIhaloQ/YBMIWjHFuYQu2CIHPGJ/hh1Mo8X1K@YzR1aZeZe0Z9CEIOE/8P03ZFuv6DIO48rfNZmUx8TJFGI5wDjt5HMWeWsjjsm4xW8@eyucCLkHISaIwdBaOMd0/TxHUim2ReNMpfH5Hg28333/4HrbpBbgtj@Fa7oPXs3zzKyvrGHZ4RrSX256wu1IS3FaBMkY6alfpb78sU5oClyJ1ywqXODfdYc01a@6wsAQDC@emO6xIsyKHhTUbWDg33WEtNOsKRTcsLObAwrnplkU/IFlfLEsXX//XjH7KDA7RCHLtEMkuA5EW7ii5KkEXq68jmiuF@4PutU8u88YRH5P1YoruRA@@cGexbu9GGfTnze2tNqh36s13W3OcM8c5cpwTxzlwpPPG@k3hX5rMlN@W@9gu/4jLwmMbnrrgvnbelCCEnN6@Ywy2wJYSMWbxOlS4UHEKJctV@FxyvX7YNFACAoak@nWVYBSDnlaUSMPJtea0oJRHlCEEpCZOqxDP18UNVJUpqDQNlLjmIsO9H1AFzPRpN5lM9iElxMvaEKW2seo4po6S4QnTENobUFLj4wuAe4MKLq0W@xNJxNuSiBGSBNpjgTLbxyoiXlFE/K8irl27@L4m3kBSY1O0v5sausTfHw5/AQ)  )